# How to increment a value with leading zeroes using php

Tags: php

Increment a value with leading zeroes using php and those numbers must be from counts in the database.  For example 0001 to 1000.

Comment: try `str_pad($i,4,".",STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use str_pad()

```
$val = 1;
echo str_pad($val,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); // 0001

$val = 10;
echo str_pad($val,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT); // 0010
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. i just keep using the last count to replace the val variable which gives it a new value in my loop.

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered by B. Desai is the correct one if you know the actual formatting of the number.

For those cases where the format is unknown (e.g. specified by the end-user), we can use the following:

```
$number = '000009'; // the number to format

str_pad(intval($number) + 1, strlen($number), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 000010
```

The code works by providing the new (i.e., increased) integer value to `str_pad` and adding the user's specified leading zeros using `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to an integer first, increment the number and convert it back to a string with padded zeroes.

```
<?php
    $number = intval('0001') + 1;
    echo sprintf('%04d', $number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$integer = 5;    
$integer++;
```

when you need the leading zeros values:

```
// The wanted number of digit you want
$digitNumber = 5;
echo sprintf('%0' . $digitNumber . 'd', $integer);

// output
00005
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split an integer into an array and then remerge it again:

```
$number = 0001;

$array  = array_map('intval', str_split($number));

$numbers = $array;
rsort($numbers);

$arrlength = count($numbers);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $numbers[$x];
}

$variable = implode(",",$numbers);
echo $variable
```

results: 1 0 0 0
         1000